# How to fill data elements from params in the cover page of an r markdown render for the automated reports

Tags: r, automation, r-markdown

I am new in R, and I am requesting anyone who can help with filling data elements in the cover page of an automated report. I previously learnt how to automate the report myself in R markdown and managed to fix the automation process without any error. The cover page needs to something like this:

```
REGION: Western 
FACILITY (IES): 3 
Total Number OF DOCTORS (S): 3 
REPORTING PERIOD: 
MONTH: January 
YEAR:2021
```

I have to tried to solve this problem but it is now two weeks down the line without any success, and I really feel giving up. I used both R and R markdown to render the report. Here is an example of the R and R Markdown codes used to render the report.

R file

```
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)

dataa<- data.frame(region = c("Coast", "Coast", "Coast", "Eastern", "Eastern","Eastern","Nairobi","Nairobi", "Rift", "Nyanza", "Nyanza", "Nyanza",
                              "Rift","Rift", "Western","Western", "Western", "North Estern"),
                  doc_id = c(1:18),
                  pat_id = c(111:128),
                  mon = rep("January", 18),
                  category = c("treated", "untreated","treated", "untreated","treated", "untreated","treated", "untreated","treated", "untreated","treated", "untreated",
                                 "treated", "untreated", "treated", "untreated", "treated", "untreated"),
                  subregion= c("Lamu","Lamu", "Mombasa","Lawi","Meru", "Maua","Kibera","Ryosambu","Migori", "Migori", "Migori","Bomet", "Nakuru", "Nakuru","Bungoma","Bungoma","Kakamega ", "Njere"),
                  subcounty = c("Lamu1","Lamu1","Kijiji","Lala","Limbo","Limbos","Kibs","Boxa","Suna East", "Suna East","Suna East", "Tenwek","Mbola","Basi", "Busi","Kak","Kibs", "Ndira"),
                  facility = c("Raburo", "God Jope", "Mura", "Township Hospital", "Kita", "Kilwe","Kihoro", "Ladu", "Kacha","Naimo", "Central","Lato","Licha","Lichas","Nayobi", "Dala","Odhus","Nyuse"),
                  Age = c("20-24","Below 15","15-19", "20-24","Below 15", "15-19","20-24","Below 15","15-19", "20-24","Below 15", "15-19", "20-24","Below 15","15-19","20-24","Below 15","15-19"))


data_1<- dataa %>% select(doc_id, region, mon, category, Age, facility, subregion, subcounty) %>% mutate(month = mon) %>% 
  filter(!category %in% NA, month %in% "January") %>% group_by(region, category, Age)%>% arrange(category, Age) %>% summarise(Quantity = n())  
View(data_1)


library(tinytex)
library(flextable)
library(kableExtra)
library(officedown)
library(knitr)
library(pander) 
library(htmlTable)
library(officedown)
library(officer)



facilities <- dataa %>% distinct(facility, .keep_all = T) %>% group_by(region) %>% summarise(docs = n())
doctors<- dataa %>% distinct(doc_id, .keep_all = T) %>% group_by(region) %>% summarise(docs = n()) 
month<- "January"
year <- 2021

for (i in unique(data_1$region)) {
  rmarkdown::render("data1.Rmd", 
                    params = list(region = i, doctors= doctors, facilities = facilities, month = month, year = year),
                    output_file=paste0(i, ".docx"))
  
}
```

Rmd file

````
---
title: "data query"
output:
  word_document: default
  pdf_document: default
date: "2022-10-29"
params:
  region: Nyanza
  facilities: facilities
  doctors: doctors
  month: January
  year: 2021
show_code: no
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = params$show_code)
library(knitr)
library(tinytex)
library(blogdown)

# picking the parameters for the report
region <- params$region
facilities<- params$facilities
doctors<- params$doctors
month<- params$month
year<- params$year

```

**REGION:** `r region` \
**FACILITY(IES):** `r facilities`\
**Total Number OF DOCTORS (S):** `r doctors`\
**REPORTING PERIOD:** \
**MONTH:**`r month` \
**YEAR:**`r year`

```{r, include=TRUE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
data_1 %>% select(-region)%>% flextable(col_keys = c("category", "Age", "Quantity")) %>% theme_box()  %>% set_caption(" ") %>% width(width = 1.5) %>% height(height = .25) %>% hrule(rule = "exact", part = "all") %>% fontsize(size = 8, part = "body")
```
````

When I run the codes above I don't get the format I need to be in the report's cover page but gets something tabular for all the regions, but I need each region to only have only total number of facilities and total number of doctors belonging to each particular region. If you run the above codes you will notice a table is produced in the second which is fine and should not be interfered with. I only request for help on how to tackle the cover page.

I am sorry if I asked a duplicated question, and will appreciate any solution to this problem.